# How to force form to show again on application startup?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Help form that shows for the first time when the application is started. After the initial startup, that form doesn't show up anymore. Is there a way to reset the show form? Here's my code to only show it once base on the application setting. When the application exit, the application sets the showform to false. <<--Need to reset on the user's computer. Reason i need this is if i have a update to application, i need to show user the updates on that help form.

```
Private Sub AboutInformation_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  If IsNewVersionAvailable() = True Then
    Dim showNextTime As Boolean
    showNextTime = My.Settings.LoadAboutForm
    If showNextTime = False Then
        Show()
        Location = New Point(0, 0)
        showNextTime = True
        My.Settings.LoadAboutForm = showNextTime
        My.Settings.Save()
    Else
        Close()
        myForm.Show()
    End If
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: So add another setting indicating if you've updated or not, or make it check if you've updated before the app is closes and then change the property.

Comment: Programmers use a version number to indicate changes.  Project > Properties > Assembly Information button > Assembly version setting.  Just increment it.  The rest is entirely automagic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a answer, I save my currentVersion in the application setting on the main form closed and on startup of the help form it checks if the previous version matches the updated version, if it doesn't it will show help form, if it does, it skips to the main for.

```
Private Sub AboutInformation_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Location = New Point(0, 0)
    'If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    Try
        Dim thisVersion As Version = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
        If thisVersion.ToString = My.Settings.CurrentVersion Then
            Dim showNextTime As Boolean
            showNextTime = My.Settings.LoadAboutForm
            If showNextTime = False Then
                Show()
                Location = New Point(0, 0)
                showNextTime = True
                My.Settings.LoadAboutForm = showNextTime
                My.Settings.Save()
            Else
                Close()
                myMainForm.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


'Saving setting for main form closed.

Private Sub myMainForm_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
        Dim currentVersion As Version = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
        Debug.Print(currentVersion.ToString)
        My.Settings.CurrentVersion = currentVersion.ToString
    End If
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```